# Как правильно читать аббревиатуру ОМТО?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия, аббревиатуры

Как правильно читать аббревиатуру ОМТО?

Comment: Развернуть или расшифровать? Ударение?

Answer (score 1):

> Как правильно читать аббревиатуру ОМТО?

По-моему, при чтении нужно произнести название каждой буквы: о-эм-тэ-о.

Comment: Добрый день!  Не хотите ли вы уделить форуму хотя бы еще немного вашего внимания, а то вас здесь не хватает.  Отвечающих немного,  а новые участники не задерживаются.  ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Это копия еще одной  просьбы, а дальше лично вам.  Я долго надеялась, что вы вернетесь,  но там стояла одна дата: февраль 2019 года. То, что вы заходили  на форум в сентябре 2020 года,  я просмотрела.  Вот вас здесь уж точно не хватает. Вы хотя бы показались, хотя бы на один вопрос ответили бы, все были бы вам очень рады.

Answer (score 0):

Сложносокращенное слово **ОМТО** (**о**тдел **м**атериально-**т**ехнического **о**беспечения) и образовано путем сочетания начальных букв слов, и читается по начальным названиям букв (буквенный тип образования аббревиатур):
**НТО** — научно-техническое общество — **эн-тэ-о**;
**МГУ** — Московский государственный университет — **эм-гэ-у**;
**ОМТО — о-эм-тэ-о́.**

Б. Р. Мандель. [Современный русский язык](https://books.google.ee/books?id=ddrhAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BC-%D1%82%D1%8D-%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=RjZhH3pUyT&sig=ACfU3U19KGMIACPTiTJEMK545t7tF1j_dQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwh6T16PDgAhWrxIsKHfwjDncQ6AEwB3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BC-%D1%82%D1%8D-%D0%BE&f=false)

ОТК (отдел технического контроля) — о-тэ-ка; ОГМ (отдел главного механика) — о-гэ-эм; НПО (научно-производственное объединение) — эн-пэ-о; НДС (налог на добавленную стоимость) — эн-дэ-эс.